# How to force some HTML to render inside some other website?

Tags: html, web-deployment, dagster

I am working with an open source ETL tool (dagster) that allows me to attach some "metadata" to the results of each operation.

Typically the metadata should be text or numbers, but I want to insert an HTML snippet.

My issue is that the HTML is not "rendering" in the tool's web-ui. Here is a quick screenshot of the UI and the source tree:

[image]

[image]

Any ideas on how I can have it "render" in the UI?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are looking for an XSS vulnerability or expecting people to download some third party software and work out how to add a feature to it. Either way, your question isn't suitable for Stackoverflow.

Comment: I meant it more as an HTML question - not sure why when I write HTML to the page it's not rendering.

Comment: Because, presumably, the tool is designed to treat it as plain text.

Comment: It is, almost sure. Do you think there is any way to modify the inserted HTML to force a render? I suppose not since that'd be a XSS vulnerability as you said. I could look to modify the Dagster code for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you can get to rendering HTML in Dagster is using the [markdown metadata type](https://docs.dagster.io/_apidocs/ops#dagster.MetadataValue.md). Rendering HTML is specifically not supported due to the possible vulnerabilities it could introduce.

Comment: Sad, plotly charts :(